# Disadvantages of having many Indexes in a SQL database?

Tags: sql, indexing

I am a database newbie and I am working on the design of my database. For efficient operation of my application I need indexes on half of my columns since with that my look will be logarithmic time.

But is there any disadvantage of having multiple indexes in a same table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- insert/update performance when indexed columns are modified will be worse
- more indexes will use more disk space